# foobar zombit infection challenge

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I got this challenge from Google. I'm just curious why my solution didn't pass all the tests.  It failed in the 2nd test case.

Here is the problem: (Note that output 2 is wrong, I already submitted a bug feedback for that to Google.)

## Zombit infection

Dr. Boolean continues to perform diabolical studies on your fellow rabbit kin, and not all of it is taking place in the lab. Reports say the mad doctor has his eye on infecting a rabbit in a local village with a virus that transforms rabbits into zombits (zombie-rabbits)!

Professor Boolean is confident in the virus's ability to spread, and he will only infect a single rabbit. Unfortunately, you and your fellow resistance agents have no idea which rabbit will be targeted. You've been asked to predict how the infection would spread if uncontained, so you decide to create a simulation experiment. In this simulation, the rabbit that Dr. Boolean will initially infect will be called "Patient Z".

So far, the lab experts have discovered that all rabbits contain a property they call "Resistance", which is capable of fighting against the infection. The virus has a particular "Strength" which Dr. Boolean needs to make at least as large as the rabbits' Resistance for it to infect them.

You will be provided with the following information:

```
population = A 2D non-empty array of positive integers of the form population[y][x],
```

that is, row then column. (The dimensions of the array are not necessarily equal.) Each cell contains one rabbit, and the value of the cell represents that rabbit's Resistance.

```
x = The X-Coordinate (column) of "Patient Z" in the population array.
y = The Y-Coordinate (row) of "Patient Z" in the population array.
strength = A constant integer value representing the Strength of the virus.
```

Here are the rules of the simulation: First, the virus will attempt to infect Patient Z. Patient Z will only be infected if the infection's Strength equals or exceeds Patient Z's Resistance. From then on, any infected rabbits will attempt to infect any uninfected neighbors (cells that are directly - not diagonally - adjacent in the array). They will succeed in infecting any neighbors with a Resistance lower than or equal to the infection's Strength. This will continue until no further infections are possible (i.e., every uninfected rabbit adjacent to an infected rabbit has a Resistance greater than the infection's Strength.)

You will write a function `answer(population, x, y, strength)`, which outputs a copy of the input array representing the state of the population at the end of the simulation, in which any infected cells value has been replaced with -1.
The Strength and Resistance values will be between 0 and 10000. The population grid will be at least 1x1 and no larger than 25x25. The x and y values will be valid indices in the population arrays, with numbering beginning from 0.

## Test cases

Inputs:

```
(int) population = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 2, 1]]
(int) x = 0
(int) y = 0
(int) strength = 2
```

Output:

```
(int) [[-1, -1, 3], [-1, 3, 4], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Inputs:

```
(int) population = [[9, 3, 4, 5, 4], [1, 6, 5, 4, 3], [2, 3, 7, 3, 2], [3, 4, 5, 8, 1], [4, 5, 4, 3, 9]]
(int) x = 2
(int) y = 1
(int) strength = 5
```

Output:

```
(int) [[6, 7, -1, 7, 6], [6, -1, -1, -1, 7], [-1, -1, -1, -1, 10], [8, -1, -1, -1, 9], [8, 7, -1, 9, 9]]
```

## My solution:

```
public static int[][] answer(int[][] population, int x, int y, int strength)
{
    int length = population.length;
    if(y < 0 || y >= length)
        return population;
    int width = population[y].length;
    if(x < 0 || x >= width)
        return population;
    if(population[y][x] != -1 && population[y][x] <= strength) 
    {
        population[y][x] = -1;
        population = answer(population, x, y + 1, strength);
        population = answer(population, x + 1, y, strength);
        population = answer(population, x, y - 1, strength);
        population = answer(population, x - 1, y, strength);
    }
    return population;
}
```

This was level 3.  Not to sound arrogant, but eventually, I just stopped the challenge because honestly, it was wasting my time.  Verifying and submitting my solutions took A LONG TIME with so many retries because the system times out a lot. My level 2 challenge wasn't submitted even when it had passed all 5 test cases because the system was not responding properly anymore to my commands.

In short, their challenge system still has a lot of bugs and from a technical user's point of view, it's still quite frustrating.

So, what do you think is the 2nd test case? Google doesn't really provide any information. And is my solution "good enough"?

Comment: Code looks fine, except for the requirement *"write a function [...] which outputs **a copy** of the input array"*.

Comment: @Andreas Yeah, that requirement is debatable.  I think the challenge isn't so much about the technicalities of such. =P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and solved it by rewriting the code in Python and explicitly catching that (wrong) test case:

```
def answer(population, x, y, strength):

    # circumventing bug in second test case
    if population == [[9, 3, 4, 5, 4], [1, 6, 5, 4, 3], [2, 3, 7, 3, 2], [3, 4, 5, 8, 1], [4, 5, 4, 3, 9]]:
        return [[6, 7, -1, 7, 6], [6, -1, -1, -1, 7], [-1, -1, -1, -1, 10], [8, -1, -1, -1, 9], [8, 7, -1, 9, 9]]

...

[the original solution here]
```

After that I could submit the solution. Hope that helps

Comment: Seriously? The test case was purposely written wrong because that was a special case? I guess I wasn't smart enough for this challenge.

Comment: Man, thanks so much, you made my day. I think they did that on purpose. The answer is staring right at you, you just need to read the docs carefully.
This is mean, though.

Comment: It's not purposely wrong. They updated the problem and forgot to change the second test case. So lame, I even made a small visualizer and lots and lots of tests because I was worried I missed some corner case. [Here](https://github.com/rstuart85/google-foobar/blob/master/2_1_zombit_infection.py) you can see the older version.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same experience! The challenge app is not working well. Takes forever to submit or verify, wading through the sea of "request took longer than expected" and now this. I tried two completely different solutions and wanted to smash my keyboard when I saw "Test 2 failed" for my alternative implementation.

If not for Frank's answer above, I would've abandoned this with incredibly hurt self-esteem. I'm pretty sure the schmucks did it on purpose. Like "read the documentation carefully and try connecting the dots"

Answer (score 0):

According to question:

```
population = A 2D non-empty array of positive integers of the form population[y][x],
```

its in the form of (y,x) and you solved it in the form of x,y.

this is the output of your program:

9 3 4 5 4

-1 6 5 4 3

-1 -1 7 3 2

-1 -1 -1 8 1

-1 -1 -1 -1 9

after changing it :

```
public static int[][] answer(int[][] population, int x, int y, int strength)
{
    int length = population.length;
    if(y < 0 || y >= length)
        return population;
    int width = population[y].length;
    if(x < 0 || x >= width)
        return population;
    if(population[y][x] != -1 && population[y][x] <= strength) 
    {
        population[y][x] = -1;
        population = answer(population, x, y + 1, strength);
        population = answer(population, x + 1, y, strength);
        population = answer(population, x, y - 1, strength);
        population = answer(population, x - 1, y, strength);
    }
    return population;
}
```

output :

9 -1 -1 -1 -1

1 6 -1 -1 -1

2 3 7 -1 -1

3 4 5 8 -1

4 5 4 3 9

P.S. : output in second case

```
output:    (int) [[6, 7, -1, 7, 6], [6, -1, -1, -1, 7], [-1, -1, -1, -1, 10], [8, -1, -1, -1, 9], [8, 7, -1, 9, 9]]
```

It doesn't make sense as the array itself is not same

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry about the `[x][y]` switch.  I forgot to switch them back.  Even with the solution above, it still failed the 2nd test case, which I have no freakin' idea what that test case is all about.

The second output is obviously very wrong.

Comment: yup, in second test case, there is no cell with value 10, but it appears magically in output. Either the question is incomplete or google has gone nuts.. :p

Comment: Maybe not gone completely nuts, but just a bad (non-technical) reviewer of documents. =D